# Switching from Angular 4 to 5 causing "Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found"

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular5, angular-module

I am porting my Angular 4 application to Angular 5 and although the application successfully builds the application does not load. I am getting the following error when I run my application: `Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.`

**Full Stack Trace**

[image]

I have tried researching for a possible solution - and I have found plenty, but none have helped. I have tried:

- Deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling everything
- Some suggested that simply making a change in the AppModule and saving solves the problem.  However after updating any file I'm always getting this error:

> ERROR in Debug Failure. False expression: Host should not return a
>   redirect source file from getSourceFile

- I've went through all my project dependencies and they are up to date
- As mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20095#issuecomment-341364333) I have updated all the rxjs imports to the correct way, i.e. do not use `import {...} from rxjs/Rx`

What I find strange is that I'm building my application using AOT however the error mentions the Jit Compiler so I'm not sure if the application is indeed trying to use AOT.

**main.browser.ts**

```
/**
 * Angular bootstrapping
 */
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';

/**
 * App Module
 * our top level module that holds all of our components
 */
import { AppModule } from './app';

/**
 * Bootstrap our Angular app with a top level NgModule
 */
export function main(): Promise<any> {
    return platformBrowserDynamic()
        .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
        .then(environment.decorateModuleRef)
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

/**
 * Needed for hmr
 * in prod this is replace for document ready
 */
switch (document.readyState) {
    case 'loading':
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _domReadyHandler, false);
        break;
    case 'interactive':
    case 'complete':
    default:
        main();
}

function _domReadyHandler() {
    document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _domReadyHandler, false);
    main();
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

/*
 * Platform and Environment providers/directives/pipes
 */
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
// App is our top level component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_RESOLVER_PROVIDERS } from './app.resolver';
import { NoContentComponent } from './no-content';

import { CoreModule, AppConfigService } from './core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppConfigLoader } from './app-config.loader';

// Application wide providers
const APP_PROVIDERS = [
    ...APP_RESOLVER_PROVIDERS
];

/**
 * `AppModule` is the main entry point into Angular2's bootstraping process
 */
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NoContentComponent
    ],
    imports: [ // import Angular's modules
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        CoreModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
        environment.ENV_PROVIDERS,
        APP_PROVIDERS,
        AppConfigService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: AppConfigLoader,
            deps: [AppConfigService],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Environment**

- **Angular:** 5.2.8
- **TypeScript:** 2.6.2
- **Webpack:** 3.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8798.
I think webpack incompatibility is the problem

Comment: Unfortunately I've already looked at that post and tried everything listed there with no luck. Also note that I'm not using Angular CLI - Still I don't think it's an Angular CLI issue, it's something to do with webpack like you said.

Comment: @DanielGrima Did you remove package-lock.json before reinstalling via `npm install`?

Comment: Good question.. thing is in my project I don't see a package-lock.json. I think this was added from NPM 5. My NPM version is 3.10.10 and node is on version 6.10.2. I don't know if the errors could be a result of my node and NPM versions. I can update and see what happens.

Comment: @Jeto unfortunately as I thought updating node and npm didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I used to have similar issues when I tried to migrate to Angular 5, I did that:

1. Removed the node_modules folder: `rm -rf node_modules`
2. Removed the webpack: `npm remove webpack`
3. Cleaned npm cahe: `npm cache clean --force`
4. Installed the latest version of angular cli: `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`
5. Installed the dependencies: `npm install`

It only worked for me after I cleaned up npm cash

Comment: I'm not using Angular CLI, tried the above without installing Angular CLI of course... still got the issue